# svelte - parse import statements in string of code

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, svelte

I am using the svelte compiler to generate code from a synthetic file (a string). The output from this is also a string but it adds import statements from svelte itself. I need to remove all of these import statements from the generated code but I also need to take these import statements and add them in a way that I can import / require from a cdn.

How can I parse out these import statements and add them to an array?

generated code for reference

```
/* generated by Svelte v3.31.2 */
import {
    SvelteComponent,
    append,
    attr,
    detach,
    element,
    init,
    insert,
    listen,
    noop,
    safe_not_equal,
    set_data,
    space,
    text
} from "svelte/internal";

function add_css() {
    var style = element("style");
    style.id = "svelte-1bt0ocf-style";
    style.textContent = "button.svelte-1bt0ocf{background:#ff3e00;color:white;border:none;padding:8px 12px;border-radius:2px}";
    append(document.head, style);
}

function create_fragment(ctx) {
    let button;
    let t0;
    let t1;
    let t2;
    let t3_value = (/*count*/ ctx[0] === 1 ? "time" : "times") + "";
    let t3;
    let mounted;
    let dispose;

    return {
        c() {
            button = element("button");
            t0 = text("Clicked ");
            t1 = text(/*count*/ ctx[0]);
            t2 = space();
            t3 = text(t3_value);
            attr(button, "class", "svelte-1bt0ocf");
        },
        m(target, anchor) {
            insert(target, button, anchor);
            append(button, t0);
            append(button, t1);
            append(button, t2);
            append(button, t3);

            if (!mounted) {
                dispose = listen(button, "click", /*handleClick*/ ctx[1]);
                mounted = true;
            }
        },
        p(ctx, [dirty]) {
            if (dirty & /*count*/ 1) set_data(t1, /*count*/ ctx[0]);
            if (dirty & /*count*/ 1 && t3_value !== (t3_value = (/*count*/ ctx[0] === 1 ? "time" : "times") + "")) set_data(t3, t3_value);
        },
        i: noop,
        o: noop,
        d(detaching) {
            if (detaching) detach(button);
            mounted = false;
            dispose();
        }
    };
}

function instance($$self, $$props, $$invalidate) {
    let count = 0;

    function handleClick() {
        $$invalidate(0, count += 1);
    }

    return [count, handleClick];
}

class Component extends SvelteComponent {
    constructor(options) {
        super();
        if (!document.getElementById("svelte-1bt0ocf-style")) add_css();
        init(this, options, instance, create_fragment, safe_not_equal, {});
    }
}

export default Component;
```

Comment: Are you trying to avoid running this through a bundler (e.g., Rollup) to inline all of those imports? If you are, you could run a find–replace on this code to replace `"svelte/internal"` with `"https://unpkg.com/svelte@3.31.2/internal/index.mjs"`, and then include a `<script>` before it in the markup: `<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/svelte@3.31.2/internal/index.mjs"></script>`. If this is for something in production you may not want to rely on a CDN, so self-host that file if you want.

Comment: Hey thanks. This is for an online code editor I am working on. I wrote my own bundler of sorts so I do run the code for each 'file' (string) through a function which create a module and then passes that through Babel standalone and bundles all 'files'.

Comment: As far as I know, Babel won't bundle multiple files together though, right? Something like webpack or Rollup would generate a single file with no dependencies. The question does make more sense with the context of an online code editor; that's a interesting problem. It might be a bit against the spirit, but you could look at the source of the code playground used by the Svelte documentation and see how they do it.

Comment: I run each file through babel separately and bundle the output myself.